# S8 Specific Bug Android: Black color bottom navigation and action bar

Tags: android, themes

I am developing an app and when I set android:background as "?attr/colorPrimary" , it appears black on s8 but appears fine on all other devices. Does anyone know what might be the reason and a fix apart from manually changing the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong, it was because of a bug in cardview and using

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
```

worked. There is also a similar issue created for google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37087169